# R: lm() with factors. Don't understand how ANOVA table calculates "Sum Sq"

Tags: r, lm, anova

I'm learning R and trying to understand how `lm()` handles factor variables & how to make sense of the ANOVA table. I'm fairly new to statistics, so please be gentle with me.

Here's some movie data from Rotten Tomatoes. I'm trying to model the score of each movie based on the mean scores for all of the movies in 4 groups: those rated G, PG, PG-13, and R.

```
download.file("http://www.rossmanchance.com/iscam2/data/movies03RT.txt", destfile = "./movies.txt")
movies <- read.table("./movies.txt", sep = "\t", header = T, quote = "")
lm1 <- lm(movies$score ~ as.factor(movies$rating))
anova(lm1)
```

and the ANOVA output:

```
## Analysis of Variance Table
## 
## Response: movies$score
##                           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
## as.factor(movies$rating)   3    570     190    0.92   0.43
## Residuals                136  28149     207
```

I understand how to get all the numbers in this table, EXCEPT `Sum Sq` and `Mean Sq` for `as.factor(movies$rating)`. Can someone please explain how that `Sum Sq` is calculated from my data? I know that `Mean Sq`is just `Sum Sq` divided by `Df`.

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll move it there.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to get that. One of them is to use the equation:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_(statistics)

SS_total = SS_reg + SS_error

So:

```
y = movies$score
sum((y - mean(y))^2) - sum(lm1$residuals^2)
```

Comment: Please note that there is an ongoing quasi-religious war (at least a disagreement with vehemently argued opposing positions)  between SAS and R authors regarding how to properly construct and partition sums-of-squares.